# Java [threads] - summarizing table with multiple threads doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am learning java, and trying to summarize elements in table with multiple threads, but I am always getting wrong result.

I tried 4 different methods of threads synchronization and all of them failed. Everything is explained in the comments.

My result (bad):

> Without threads: 4949937, 15ms
>   With threads: 4944805, 78ms

Maybe am I executing the System.out.println on summarizeT() too early? I mean before all the threads finish work. With .join() the summarizeT() method works good but. Is the .join() blocking the "main" thread until all other threads are finished?

Main class:

```
public class Main 
{
static int size = 100000; //size of tab
static int length = 100; //each thread gets 100 elements of tab, thread 1 calculates sum from 0 to 99, thread 2 from 100 to 199 etc.
static int[] tab = new int[size];

static Random generator = new Random();

static void initialize()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        tab[i] = generator.nextInt(100);
}

static int summarize() //summarize with only one thread
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sum += tab[i];
    return sum;
}

static int summarizeT() //summarize with more threads (size / length)
{
    int threadsCounter = size/length;
    int start = 0; //pointer to table from where each thread should start counting
    int[] sum = new int[1]; //I am sharing the sum value between threads with table, not sure if it is best method to pass the value between them
    sum[0] = 0;
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadsCounter]; //nedeed for .join() test
    for (int i = 0; i < threadsCounter; i++)
    {
        threads[i] = new Thread(new MyThread(tab, start, sum));
        threads[i].start();
        start += length; //moving the start pointer, next thread should start counting from next 100 indexes 
    }
    /*for (int i = 0; i < threadsCounter; i++) // adding .join() solves the problem, but is it a good solution?
    {
        try {
            threads[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }*/
    return sum[0];
}


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    initialize();
    long start = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println("Without threads: " + summarize() + ", " + (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - start) + "ms");
    start = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println("With threads: " + summarizeT() + ", " + (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - start) + "ms"); //giving wrong answer
}
}
```

MyThread class:

```
  import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

  public class MyThread extends Thread
  {
int[] tab;
int[] sum;
int start;

         MyThread(int tab[], int start, int sum[]) //in args: main table, starting index, value that is being shared between threads
{
    this.tab = tab;
    this.start = start;
    this.sum = sum;
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    int end = start + Main.length; //place where thread should stop counting
    int temp = 0; //nedeed to sumarize the "subtable"
    while (start < end)
    {
        temp += tab[start];
        start++;
    }

    // Method 1
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    try {
        semaphore.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try 
    {
        sum[0] += temp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
       semaphore.release();
    }

    // Method 2
    /*Object lock = new Object();
    synchronized(lock)
    {
        sum[0] += temp;
    }*/

    // Method 3
    /*synchronized(this)
    {
        sum[0] += temp;
    }*/

    // Method 4
    //summarize(temp);

    // Method 5 - no threads synchronization, works only when .join() is used, the same as other methods
    //sum[0] += temp;
}

private synchronized void summarize(int value)
{
    sum[0] += value;
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't link to code; post (relevant) code directly in your question.  Thanks.

Comment: done, but stackoverflow has some problems with formatting

Comment: What is `Main.length` ? I didnt see this in your class too

Comment: Main.length is static value from Main class: static int length = 100; - it is right under int size

Comment: Am I misreading this - the two answers you that your code produces appear to be the same - the Threaded one took longer which I guess is unexpected. So what do you consider to be the problem - the value produced, or the time taken to produce it?

Comment: By the way - you WILL need to wait for all the thread that you spawn to complete - using `join` is a reasonable way of doing this. If you don;t have some form of wait in operation the main thread is not suspended, so is likely to terminate before the other threads finish their work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed, the two answers are accidentaly the same. I have fixed it. Sorry about that, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the problem here that you create a lock object , or semaphore object, in each thread, rather than having one object that *all* threads synchronise on?

Each Thread creates is own Semaphore object ( for example ) so no other thread will ever contend with it. You need to create an object that ALL threads have access to and synchronise on that. You might consider synchronising on the array that you are writing the results in to itself.

Comment: I suggest `synchronized (sum)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your solution.

You should use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) to hold results. that way you don't need to synchronize sum update.

BTW the way you synchronize is invalid. For semaphores to work you need to share same instance between all threads. And your try/catch/finally blocks are invalid. You should do `acquire()` and sum update in one try block, and `release()` in it's finally. That way you did it. It is possible that you'll do sum update even though `acquire()` failed.

Also you return from `summarizeT()` without waiting for threads to finish. You have to implement `thread.join()` logic or some other way to wait.